# is there a equivalent of Java's labelled break in C# or a workaround

Tags: c#, break, labeled-statements

I am converting some Java code to C# and have found a few labelled "break" statements (e.g.)

```
label1:
    while (somethingA) {
       ...
        while (somethingB) {
            if (condition) {
                break label1;
            }
        }
     }
```

Is there an equivalent in C# (current reading suggests not) and if not is there any conversion other than (say) having bool flags to indicate whether to break at each loop end (e.g.)

```
bool label1 = false;
while (somethingA)
{
   ...
    while (somethingB)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            label1 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (label1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
// breaks to here
```

I'd be interested as to why C# doesn't have this as it doesn't seem to be very evil.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can just use [`goto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) to jump directly to a label.

```
while (somethingA)
{
    // ...
    while (somethingB)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            goto label1;
        }
    }
}
label1:
   // ...
```

In C-like languages, `goto` often ends up cleaner for breaking nested loops, as opposed to keeping track of boolean variables and repeatedly checking them at the end of each loop.

Comment: You're welcome.  I didn't realize Java had labeled statements, so that makes us even :P

Comment: A `return` is cleaner, if you can structure it that way.

Comment: @MarkRushakoff, you should edit your answer... he wasn't really asking about boolean variables for loop control, so you shouldn't confuse the issue by bringing them up.  In addition, goto is not really as good as labeled breaks because goto does not enforce branching only to the exit of a block... you can goto anywhere

Comment: @JoelFan I would like to point out to future readers that `goto` is limited to the scope of the containing method, and is unable to jump over variable declarations. You cannot jump outside of the containing method. This rings true even today in `C#`.