# Switch Case Causing Trouble In Going To A particular Function

Tags: c#

```
     FunWithScheduling fun = new FunWithScheduling();
     Console.WriteLine("This Is Your Scheduler");
     Console.WriteLine("What Do You Wish To Do");
     Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 To Add, 2 To Edit, 3 To Search And 4 To Exit");
     int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     switch (Choice)
     {
              case 1:
                  goto fun.Add();
                  break;
              case 2:
                  goto fun.Edit();
                  break;
              case 3:
                  goto fun.Search();
                  break;
              case 4:
                  goto fun.Exit();
                  break;
             Default:
                   Console.WriteLine("Enter a Valid Number");   
                   return;
      }
 }
```

I got 4 functions that would help me do the following
Add
Edit
Search
Exit

I want to use switch case to go to the function. Is it possible?
It asked for an object reference and then a label.

Comment: you shouldn't place the _goto_ word there. Even if a method needed to be prefix, it would be _call_. But that isn't needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just call the method without the goto ? and for me it's not the proper way to use a goto, cfr [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This should be ok for me :

```
FunWithScheduling fun = new FunWithScheduling();
 Console.WriteLine("This Is Your Scheduler");
 Console.WriteLine("What Do You Wish To Do");
 Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 To Add, 2 To Edit, 3 To Search And 4 To Exit");
 int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 switch (Choice)
 {
          case 1:
              fun.Add();
              break;
          case 2:
              fun.Edit();
              break;
          case 3:
              fun.Search();
              break;
          case 4:
              fun.Exit();
              break;
         Default:
               Console.WriteLine("Enter a Valid Number");   
               return;
  }
```

}

Comment: unreachable code detected, This label has not been referenced.

Comment: Can you post the content of FunWithScheduling class ? @JoanahJocks

Comment: Sorry Sir, Its too huge. I am not able format it here in this blog

Comment: Ok, from what I read, you're defining some goto label in this class. It's a bit out of scope but I think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906056/goto-is-this-bad and start using methods instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `goto`. Those are only used if you are using labels. Simply call `fun.Add()` or `fun.Edit()`., etc.