# Update class property inside Enumerable.Zip linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I want to update every class property in IEnumerable from the external list.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }            
}
```

I tried the following

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var myclasses = Enumerable.Repeat(new MyClass(), numbers.Count);  

myclasses.Zip(numbers, (a, b) => a.Value = b).ToList();           // Set each property [Not working as expected]
myclasses.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));      // Print all properties
```

I expect that previous code will set `Value` property in `myclasses` with 1,2,3 respectivelly. But this code set `3` in every property and prints:

```
OUTPUT:
3
3
3
```

I don't understand this behavior. Can someone explain me why this happened and what is proper way to do this using LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Repeat(a, b)` generates a sequence that contains `b` times `a`. So you get a sequence that contains three times the **same** instance (you only instantiate **one** `new MyClass()`).

So by the last execution of `a.Value = b` you set the `Value` property of your single `MyClass` instance to `3`, and the `x` in your `WriteLine` is always the *same instance, containing `Value = 3`*.

A better way to create `myclasses` would be

```
var myclasses = Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Count).Select(i => new MyClass());
```

**Note** that it's [often a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001032/5528593) to create sequences with side effects. You actually don't use the sequence returned by `Zip` but use this *query* only for it's side effects inside your lambda.

I guess in your real application the creation of `myclasses` and the update via `Zip` is more separated than in your question. But if not, you could reduce it all to this:

```
var myclasses = numbers.Select(i => new MyClass { Value = i });
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why you now only get `0`s as output is the *deferred exeuction* (again: using functional programming methods like linq only for its side effects is tricky).

The immediate solution is to add `ToList` to the creation:

```
var myclasses = Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Count).Select(i => new MyClass()).ToList();
```

Without that, the classes are instantiated only at this line:

```
myclasses.Zip(numbers, (a, b) => a.Value = b).ToList();
```

And the created classes are *returned as a sequence* which is then turned in to a `List` by `ToList()`. But you don't use that return value.

So in the next line

```
myclasses.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
```

you creat **new instances** of the classes.

`myclasses` as you defined it is only a **query**, not the **answer** to that query.

So my final proposal:

```
var myclasses = Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Count).Select(i => new MyClass());
var updatedClasses = myclasses.Zip(numbers, (a, b) => {a.Value = b; return a;}).ToList(); 
updatedClasses.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
```

**Note** that I changed the lambda in `Zip` to return the instance of the class instead of the `int`.

Comment: Yes, creation of `myclasses` is separated from the question, I am only interesing in updates with `Zip`. I corrected creation of `myclassess` using `Enumerable.Range` as you wrote, but this still don't work. In that case `Zip` will do nothing (it will print all zeros). Again, I don't understand why the property setter is not called.

Comment: I can't beleve that I made several mistakes just in few lines :). Tnx for good explanation.