# In a c# switch, can I use a case as default?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Can I refer to a case in default instead of copy-pasting the whole code?

For example:

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //code here...
        break;
    case(2): //code here...
        break;
    case(3): //code here...
        break;
    default: case(2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. Why don't you just remove the `case(2)` and put the code in `default`? It's not necessary to list all options as `case`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put it second to last, followed by `default`:

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //code here...
        break;
    case(3): //code here...
        break;
    case(2):
    default: //code here...
        break;
}
```

Or simply, not include it at all. If that case isn't hit, then it will fall back to the default anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this. If there is no case, it will got to the `default`.

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //code here...
        break;
    case(3): //code here...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

No need to do

```
case(2):
default: //code here...
     break;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer default to case 2, you can omit case 2. Then every case 2 should jump to case default.

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //code here...
        break;

    case(3): //code here...
        break;

    default:  //case 2 should jump to this section because its not listed in your switch-cases
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
switch(n)
{
    case(1): //code here...
        break;
    case(3): //code here...
        break;
    case(2):
    default: 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any code in the `default` case, you can simply omit case 2 and move that code to the default, like the other answers say.

If you do have code that has to be run in the `default` case before you want to move on to case 2, you can use a `goto`. Here's an example using `int`:

```
int n = 5;
switch(n)
{
    case 1: //code here...
        break;
    case 2: //code here...
        break;
    case 3: //code here...
        break;
    default:
        //some code
        goto case 2;
}
```

Comment: Oh god no. [Never use `goto`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906056/goto-is-this-bad).

Comment: this is the correct answer and this is the reason a goto statement exists in C#.

Comment: @DanielFuchs If the case for 2 is _exactly_ the same as default, then no, there is no reason whatsoever to do this. And goto should be avoided like the plague anyway.

Comment: @FrankerZ Let's not hold this discussion here, but goto is not evil. (at least in C#). If you can't use goto, you shouldn't use break, continue or any other jump statement either. This is the standard way of doing this in C#.

Comment: @Dennis_E I've seen the actual way switch-case is supposed to work on assembler level, and I'm fairly sure the c# implementation is hardly recognizable next to it. Switch-case, unlike for/while/if, actually exists as an elegant thing on bytecode level.

Comment: This is terrible.  Whomever changes case 2 in the future has to be aware they are changing the default as well.  The code for case 2 should be wrapped in a method, and then called in case 2 and the default case instead.  That would make the code much easier to understand and future updates much less risky.  Down voting the answer.