# (C# 'Random' is a namespace but is used like a variable) I don't understand why

Tags: c#, .net, random

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Random.");    
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        choosing:

        Console.WriteLine("Roll Standard Dice (D), Flip a Coin (2), 8-Ball (8), or Random Number 1-10 (R)");

        ConsoleKeyInfo result = Console.ReadKey();    
        if ((result.KeyChar == 'D') || (result.KeyChar == 'd'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Standard Dice Has been chosen, do you want to continue? Y/N");    
            ConsoleKeyInfo RSD = Console.ReadKey();

            if ((RSD.KeyChar == 'Y') || (RSD.KeyChar == 'y'))
            {
                Console.Write("Rolling");    
                Console.Write(".");    
                Console.Write(".");    
                Console.Write(".");    
            }
            else if ((RSD.KeyChar == 'N') || (RSD.KeyChar == 'n'))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                goto choosing;
            }
        }
        else if ((result.KeyChar == '2'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I wont do anything");
        }
        else if ((result.KeyChar == '8'))
        {
        }
        else if ((result.KeyChar == 'R') || (result.KeyChar == 'r'))
        {
        }

        *Random* rnd = new *Random*();
    }
}
```

The parts in asterix are the part where it is a red line and it says Random is a namespace but it's used like a variable. The Random thing normally works but I'm not sure why it isn't working now if you could please help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `goto`! [goto is this bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11906056/6400526)

Comment: Yeah, I can only support @Gilad Green in this. I know, it has nothing to do with the question (which is already answered), but **never** use go-to, you will end up with Spaghetti code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code.

Comment: dude! why did you remove the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your project's namespace is also Random, change it to some other name,

**`namespace Random`**

to

**`namespace Sample`**

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, ill put you as the answer when I can. (it's not letting me right now....)

Comment: Another option is to use `System.Random` which will work. Still better to just have a different namespace

Comment: yeah @GiladGreen

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a type with the same name as the namespace it's in. Don't do that. Change you namespace to some other name than **Random**

Some further instructions on [Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)

Comment: what is different from the above answer?

Comment: Explanation @Sajeetharan . You made clear what to do , but havent explained. That's y I haven't posted the code as its already there ;)