# is a namespace but is used like a variable

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Error : when i am trying to call language folder the next message appear as an error message "***WebApplication5.language is a namespace but is used like a variable***"
[image]

Comment: Folder != namespace, but Visual Studio, by default, will namespace classes, etc. by the folder they're in. Don't you need something like WebApplication5.language.myresource.???

Comment: similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397572/c-random-is-a-namespace-but-is-used-like-a-variable-i-dont-understand-why

Comment: i want to access myresource file so i have to call it from parent , webapplication5"namespace".language"namespace".myresource"class".Property

Comment: @ahmed That's correct, yes. You need to use `WebApplication5.language.myresource.Property` as you have described.

Comment: @WebApplication5.language.myresource (inaccessabile due to its protection level) whats solution now

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution. You need to prepare the class named "`myresource`" as a public and all their members should be public so they can read their namespace "`language`" but not as a variable.