# lazily building up an enumerable with breaks in between

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, enumerable

I have a collection of objects `IEnumerable<object> obs`.
I have another collection of objects `IEnumerable<object> data`.

For each `ob` in `obs` I need to find the first item in `data` that has the same value in a certain property as `ob`. For example I could be looking for the first item in `data` that has the same `ToString()` value as `ob`. When the first item where the property values match is found, I do something with the found data item and then I check the next `ob` in `obs`. If none is found, I throw an error.

Here is a naive approach:

```
foreach (object ob in obs)
{
    foreach (object dataOb in data)
        if (ob.ToString() == dataOb.ToString())
        {
            ... // do something with dataOb
            goto ContinueOuter;
        }
    throw new Exception("No matching data found.");

    ContinueOuter: ;
}
```

The disadvantage is that I calculate `dataOb.ToString()` every time, which is unnecessary.
I could cache it:

```
IDictionary<object, string> dataToDataStr = new Dictionary<object, string>();
foreach (object dataObj in data) // collect all ToString values in advance
    dataToDataStr.Add(dataObj, dataObj.ToString());

foreach (object ob in obs)
{
    foreach (object dataOb in dataToDataStr.Keys)
        if (ob.ToString() == dataToDataStr[dataOb])
        {
            ... // do something with dataOb
            goto ContinueOuter;
        }
    throw new Exception("No matching data found.");

    ContinueOuter: ;
}
```

The disadvantage is that I calculate all `ToString()` values even though it might not be necessary. I might find all matching data objects in the first half of the data collection.

**How can I build up the `dataToDataStr` dictionary (or any other enumerable data structure that lets me retrieve both the object and its only-once-calculated ToString value) lazily?**

Here is code (mixed with pseudocode) of what I have in mind:

```
IDictionary<object, string> dataToDataStr = new Dictionary<object, string>();
object lastProcessedDataOb = null;

foreach (object ob in obs)
{
    foreach (object dataOb in dataToDataStr.Keys)
        if (ob.ToString() == dataToDataStr[dataOb])
        {
            ... // do something with dataOb
            goto ContinueOuter;
        }

    foreach (object dataOb in data STARTING AFTER lastProcessedDataOb)
    // if lastProcessedDataOb == null, start with the first entry of data
    {
        dataToDataStr.Add(dataOb, dataOb.ToString();
        lastProcessedDataOb = dataOb;

        if (ob.ToString() == dataToDataStr[dataOb])
        {
            ... // do something with dataOb
            goto ContinueOuter;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No matching data found.");

    ContinueOuter: ;
}
```

I know it is easy if `data` was a `LinkedList` or any collection with indexed access (then I could store a linked list node or an index as `lastProcessedDataOb`), but it isn't - it is an `IEnumerable`. Maybe `yield return` can be used here?

Comment: Maybe you should describe why you compare your objects via ToString in the first place. That feels wrong. Why don't you use the standard way of implementing Equals/GetHashcode or a proper implementation of the IEquatable/IComparable Interfaces? The implementation might than contain a caching mechanisms if calculating is expensive. That would make life easier for the users of such classes.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with the point of the question (building up enumerables lazily). Also, I did write "I need to find the first item in data that has the same value in a certain property as ob. FOR EXAMPLE [...] `ToString` [...]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collections are really large and you really don't want to evaluate `ToString` for each item of `data`, you could use the following approach:

1. Create cache of already calculated items
2. If certain item is found i cache - that's great, we have a match.
3. Otherwise - continue populating cache by iterating over `data` collection until we find a match. This can be efficiently be done with manually controlling `**Enumerator**` of data collection (instead of using `foreach`).

   ```
   IEnumerable<object> obs;
   IEnumerable<object> data;
   Dictionary<string, object> dataCache = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   var dataIterator = data.GetEnumerator();
   foreach (var ob in obs)
   {
       var obText = ob.ToString();
       object matchingDataItem = null;
       if (!dataCache.TryGetValue(obText, out matchingDataItem))
       {
           while (dataIterator.MoveNext())
           {
               var currentData = dataIterator.Current;
               var currentDataText = currentData.ToString();
               if (!dataCache.ContainsKey(currentDataText)) // Handle the case when data collection contains duplicates
               {
                   dataCache.Add(currentDataText, currentData);
                   if (currentDataText == obText)
                   {
                       matchingDataItem = currentData;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       if (matchingDataItem != null)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Matching item found for " + obText);
       }
       else
       {
           throw new Exception("No matching data found.");
       }
   }
   ```

This way you can **guarantee to iterate over `data` collection only to the point when all `obs` items are found and you won't evaluate `ToString` for each item more then once**.

*PS:* I hope "ToString" is just for example and you have some complex calculations there, which is worth such complexities...

Comment: There should be a check if `dataCache` already contains the key `currentDataText` before the `Add` call. In case the key exists, do a `continue`.

Comment: You still check for string equality (`currentDataText == obText`) in case the key is a duplicate. This is not necessary as it has already been checked via`dataCache.TryGetValue(...)` earlier.

Comment: Added that optimization as well, although it looks tiny.

Answer (score -1):

Totally forgot that LINQ uses lazy evaluation...
This should work (I use the new value tuple notation of C# 7):

```
IEnumerable<(object, string)> objStrPairs = data.Select(o => (o, o.ToString()));
foreach (object ob in obs)
{
    foreach ((object, string) dataPair in objStrPairs)
        if (ob.ToString() == objStrPairs.Item2)
        {
            ... // do something with objStrPairs.Item1
            goto ContinueOuter;
        }
    throw new Exception("No matching data found.");

    ContinueOuter: ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using `goto`? That's not deprecated only for compatibility reasons...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Java has the possibility to name a loop - e.g. the outer loop could be named "outer" - and then, deep inside a nested loop, call `continue outer`. Since C# doesn't have this feature, `goto` is the way to go.

Comment: The common way to go is understanding that c# is not java. Normally, one would add a boolean variable to the outer loop to know what happened in the inner loop. You could also even use a single LINQ statement for this entire answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto "You could also even use a single LINQ statement for this entire answer." Please share your answer then!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Regarding your comment about `goto`, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913707/5333340

Comment: If you are afraid of calculating redundant items in collection (O(N)) complexity, why do you iterate over data collection again and again for each item, making it O(N*N) complexity even not getting to the end of collection...