# Reiterating a Try statement using GoTo in the Catch clause?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am examining some code examples and have seen similar variation to the following examples, one of them made me very curious.

When a `goto_tag` is placed before a `try` statement. This makes complete sense and it just runs through the `try` again.

```
retry_tag: //the goto tag to re-attempt to copy a file

try {
    fileInfo.CopyTo( toAbsolutePath + fileInfo.Name, true ); //THIS LINE MIGHT FAIL IF BUSY
} catch {
    Thread.Sleep(500); //wait a little time for file to become available.
    goto retry_tag; //go back and re-attempt to copy
}
```

However, as the following was presented to me I did not understand it. When a `goto_tag` is placed within the `try` statement, and is called from within the `catch` block.

```
try {
    retry_tag: //the goto tag to re-attempt to copy a file

    fileInfo.CopyTo( toAbsolutePath + fileInfo.Name, true ); //THIS LINE MIGHT FAIL IF BUSY
} catch {
    Thread.Sleep(500); //wait a little time for file to become available.
    goto retry_tag; //go back and re-attempt to copy
}
```

Is the `try` block resurrected? Or are the two examples functionally identical, or is this an completely illegal operation and won't even compile?

This is all purely out of curiosity, and of course I would prefer the first example, if either of them..

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: Do not use goto! Just use a loop. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11906056/6400526, or: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/6400526

Comment: Use some loop instead, e.g. `while`. And don´t catch exceptions that you can avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually answer your question:

No, these are *not* the same.

The first example will compile; the second is illegal.

(The matter of whether you should write code like this is a different question... and off course, you should not if you can help it.)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the `goto` and do not use it typically. I shall adhere to your words of wisdom and avoid patterns such as these. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple `while` instead of `goto`:

```
// loop until ... 
while (true) {
  try {
    fileInfo.CopyTo(Path.Combine(toAbsolutePath, fileInfo.Name), true); 

    // ... file copied
    break;
  } 
  catch (IOException) {
    Thread.Sleep(500); //wait a little time for file to become available.       
  } 
}
```

Comment: I am correcting the `goto` example mentioned previously in favor of this. Thank you