# calling goto label with label in different method

Tags: c#, goto

I want to call a label which is in method1 and the goto statement is in method2.
Can I do this? if yes, How?
I tried to this but it gives the error that the lable is found

Comment: Without seeing your code it is hard to say anything, but you need to rethink about the way you are going to do in the first place, as it is not recommended to use the `goto` statement nowadays, FYI.

Comment: @SalahAkbari my label is in the form load method and my goto statement is in btn click method.Why goto statement is not recommended?

Comment: what should i use instead of goto?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906056/is-using-a-goto-statement-bad

Comment: _Why goto statement is not recommended?_ Because __it will lead to disaster__. The only reson to ever ever ever use it is to __jump forward__ out of a deeply nested loop. Your case is the opposite and a prime example of unstructured code.

Comment: @TaW Even that feels bad. The only reason I can think of is to purposefully direct C# to fall through a switch case which is otherwise forbidden (which just syntactically uses the `goto` keyword, not a label and jump).

Comment: _Even that feels bad_ Well, imo that's just our education. Once you have been there and tested the alternatives you learn to accept it. `Switch` always feels bad to me: All those ridiculousl `break` statements without any real puspose other than pimpering c coders..