# Goto statement in filesystem exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, filesystems, goto

```cs
save:
try
{
    s.Save();
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    FSErrorDialog fsError = new(ex, FSVerb.Access, new FileInfo(path), Button.Retry, Button.Ignore);
    if (fsError.ShowDialog().ClickedButton == Button.Retry)
    {
        goto save;
    }
}
```

The `Save()` method saves the object to the disk.
If an exogenous exception occurs, the user is prompted to retry the operation to avoid loosing unsaved data.

I know I could use a `while (true)` loop with break statements but I think the goto approach is more readable. It also saves an indentation level.

I am scared of using goto.

Is this a legitimate use of goto statements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906056/is-using-a-goto-statement-bad
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful#:~:text=A%20coworker%20of%20mine%20said%20the%20only%20reason%20to%20use%20a%20GOTO%20is%20if%20you%20programmed%20yourself%20so%20far%20into%20a%20corner%20that%20it%20is%20the%20only%20way%20out.%20In%20other%20words%2C%20proper%20design%20ahead%20of%20time%20and%20you%20won%27t%20need%20to%20use%20a%20GOTO%20later.
Interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest declaring a boolean to track if you should retry. That way you can use a do/while loop:

```cs
bool shouldRetry;
do
{
    try
    {
        s.Save();
        shouldRetry = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        FSErrorDialog fsError = new(ex, FSVerb.Access, new FileInfo(AppDirectory.Scripts.Join(s.FilePath)), Button.Retry, Button.Ignore);
        shouldRetry = fsError.ShowDialog().ClickedButton == Button.Retry;
    }
}
while (shouldRetry);
```

To address the "more readable" aspect that you mentioned in the question, I think this is more readable for 2 reasons:

1. We're using something that exists explicitly as a loop, so it's clear from the beginning that looping is possible. You don't need to find the `goto` to work out that it loops.
2. The variable name `shouldRetry` makes it abundantly clear *why* we are looping: because we need to retry.

Comment: Not initializing shouldRetry to a default value allows for a compile-time guarantee that shouldRetry is set in all code paths (otherwise you get CS0165)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *infinite loop*; we loop until either we have no exception or when we decide to stop our attempts:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    s.Save();

    break; // No more looping (success)
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    FSErrorDialog fsError = new(ex, FSVerb.Access, new FileInfo(path), Button.Retry, Button.Ignore);
    
    if (fsError.ShowDialog().ClickedButton != Button.Retry)
      break; // No more looping (no more tries)  
  }
}
```